# Degree of the direct image of a line bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, riemann-surfaces

Consider a $n$-branched cover $\pi:S\rightarrow M$, where $S$ and $M$ are both algebraic curves. If $\pi_{0}: L\rightarrow S$ is a line bundle over $S$, we can define the bundle $\pi_{*}L$ on $M$ given by:
$$
H^{0}(U, \pi_{*}L):=H^{0}(\pi^{-1}(U), L)
$$
My goal is to calculate $\deg(\pi_{*}L)$.

Using the Riemann-Roch theorem, we find the two following equations:

\begin{align}
&\dim H^{0}(S, L)-\dim H^{0}(S, K_{S}\otimes L^{*})=\deg(L)+1-g(S)\\
&\dim H^{0}(M, \pi_{*}L)-\dim H^{0}(S,K_{M}\otimes(\pi_{*}L)^{*})=\deg(\pi_{*}L)+1-g(M)
\end{align}

Since $\dim H^{0}(S, L)=\dim H^{0}(M, \pi_{*}L)$, to determine the degree of $\pi_{*}L$ it is enough to calculate the term $\dim H^{0}(S, K_{S}\otimes L^{*})$. Is there any relation between $\dim H^{0}(S, K_{S}\otimes L^{*})$ and $\dim H^{0}(S, K_{M}\otimes (\pi_{*}L)^{*})$?

Comment: Since $\pi $ is affine, $\chi (\pi _*L)=\chi (L)$. The relation you want follows immediately.

Comment: Note: $\pi_* L$ is not an invertible sheaf, and its rank should appear in the RR formula. The $+$ signs on the LHS in RR should be minus signs.

Comment: OK, since apparently you didn't read my comment, here is the formula: $$\deg \pi _*L= n(g(M)-1)+\chi (\pi _*L)=n(g(M)-1)+\chi (L)=\deg(L)+n(g(M)-1)-(g(S)-1)\,.$$

Comment: Thanks, @abx! I read your comment yesterday and it was very useful. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: No problem, happy it was useful.